# split file into time period files based on time unix stamp

Tags: bash, unix, awk, timestamp

I have some thousands of log (.txt) files (their names or order does not matter, neither does the order of entries in the final output files) which consist of a unix time stamp and a value, such as:

```
infile1.txt:
1361775157 a
1361775315 b            
1379007707 c
1379014884 d

infile2.txt:
1360483293 e
1361384920 f
1372948120 g
1373201928 h
```

My goal is to split them based into arbitrarily defined time intervals (e.g. in this case with 1360000000, 1370000000 and 1380000000 as the bounds), so that I get as many files as intervals:

```
1360000000-1370000000.txt:
1361775157 a 
1361775315 b    
1360483293 e
1361384920 f        

1370000000-1380000000.txt:
1379007707 c
1379014884 d
1372948120 g
1373201928 h
```

My current approach is to run a script that filters the entries of each period in a loop for each time period (start and end as first and second argument) and adds them to a file:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in *txt; do
    awk -v t1=$1 -v t2=$2 '$1 >= t1 && $1 < t2' $i >> "elsewhere/$1-$2.txt"
done
```

However, this means that for each time period all files are read, which seems inefficient to me. Is there a way to read each file only once, and append each line to a file corresponding to its time period?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show some example content of your input files, that shows how does `unixtimestamp` looks like. Show also how you would specify the time ranges and how the file names look like. Do the file names somehow correspond to the order of the files?

Comment: thanks for the responses! I've added some more information which I hope makes it more clear what I'm aiming for.

Comment: I think instead of a bunch of text files, I'd store everything in a sqlite database with an index on the timestamp column. That makes getting any arbitrary interval trivial (`SELECT * FROM messages WHERE timestamp BETWEEN :start_time AND :end_time`), allows for more complicated queries on top of timeframes, and one file is a lot easier to manage than thousands.

Comment: You should fix your desired output file names so `1370000000` isn't part of multiple file names and specifically isn't part of a file name that it can't appear in. Do you REALLY want to have to call a script with a list of`1360000000,1370000000,1380000000, etc.` boundaries or do you instead want to just say `every 10000000 starting from 1360000000` or `every 10000000 from 1360000000 to 9750000000` or similar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use an approach like this:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    bucket = int($1/inc)
    print $0 " > " ( (inc*bucket) "-" (inc*(bucket+1)-1) ".txt" )
}

$ awk -v inc='10000000' -f tst.awk file1 file2
1361775157 a > 1360000000-1369999999.txt
1361775315 b > 1360000000-1369999999.txt
1379007707 c > 1370000000-1379999999.txt
1379014884 d > 1370000000-1379999999.txt
1360483293 e > 1360000000-1369999999.txt
1361384920 f > 1360000000-1369999999.txt
1372948120 g > 1370000000-1379999999.txt
1373201928 h > 1370000000-1379999999.txt
```

If you're using GNU awk (which handles closing/reopening files for you when needed) then just change `$0 " > "` to `>` when done testing, otherwise make it:

```
{
    bucket = int($1/inc)
    if ( bucket != prev ) {
        close(out)
        out = (inc*bucket) "-" (inc*(bucket+1)-1) ".txt"
        prev = bucket
    }
    print >> out
}
```

to work in any awk.